# "what did Diane say?" vs "what Diane said?"

Tags: questions

> what did Diane say?
>
> what Diane said?

How do you understand which one is correct? The book that i study myself says if question words(**who/what**) is **subject** of the sentence **do/did** is omitted. My problem is that i can not understand if its **subject** or **object** of the sentence.

another example:

> Who lives here?
>
> Who does live here?

To me, both sounds correct. So my question: is there a way to find the correct form without looking subjects or objects of the sentence. and does native speakers find the correct form like i do? Thanks

Comment: These are questions, not question tags. In both examples, the first alternative is correct. A question tag would be "Diane said that, **did she**?"

Comment: @KateBunting yeah i mean words. Question words

Comment: Your book is correct. In _Who lives here?_, 'who' is the subject. If a person is the subject - _Does Diane live here?_ 'do' is required.

Comment: This question has been asked before in various forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) How do you understand which one is correct?**

You should identify the subject and object. It would be very unusual for "Diane" to be the object of the verb "say", so we can assume that it is instead the subject. In that case, "what" is the object, so we need an auxiliary verb:

> What did Diane say?

---

**2) is there a way to find the correct form without looking subjects or objects of the sentence.**

In general, you should identify subjects and objects to be sure that you are structuring clauses correctly. However, sometimes other factors will determine the verb form. For example, in your last example ("Who lives here?" / "Who does live here?"), both versions are grammatically correct and the auxiliary verb is used for emphasis.

---

**3) does native speakers find the correct form like i do?**

How you find the correct form is unclear. The book that you're using might not be very accurate. (As I mentioned, the auxiliary verb "to do" is possible even when the subject is a wh-word.)

Answer (score 0):

Correct: **What did Diane say?** (What-object, Diane-subject) [ Incorrect: what Diane said? ]

Correct: **Who lives here?** (Who-subject) [ Incorrect: Who does live here? ]

He lives here.(subject-He)

Who lives here? (subject-Who)

What happens? What happened? (What-subject)

What **do** you want? What **do** you say? (What-object, you-subject)

Who saw you? (Who-subject)

Who **did** you see? (Who-object, you-subject)

**[** What did Diane say? Tell me **what Diane said**. Do you know **what Diane said**? I don't know **what Diane said**. **]**

Comment: in the sentence of `what happens/happened`, how did you understand that `what` is the subject

Comment: _What?_ represents the thing that happened, not the thing that something happened to.

Comment: **Who does live here?** is possible in certain contexts, such as: **Well, if John doesn't live here, who does live here?**